# Observe an RxSwift.BehaviorRelay just **before** a change happens

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive

In RxSwift, how can I observe a `BehaviorRelay` just **before** a change happens?

I tried:

```
object.subscribe(onNext: {...})
```

with which I get a notification only **after** the new value has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. The work around depends on why you want the previous value. If, for example, you want to compare the previous value to the new value, you can do that with `.scan`. An operator like this would do it:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func withPrevious() -> Observable<(Element?, Element)> {
        scan((Element?.none, Element?.none)) { ($0.1, $1) }
        .map { ($0.0, $0.1!) }
    }
}
```

And the standard disclaimer:

> Subjects [and Relays] provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use... Instead of using subjects, favor the factory methods... -- [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com)

Comment: Thank you! I’d like to use `objectWillChange.send()` on an Combine `ObservableObject` with RxSwift properties.

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to inform my (SwiftUI) UI of changes in the ObservableObject, so the UI (which uses data from the ObservableObject) can update accordingly.

Comment: Don't you need the new value to do that?

Comment: As far as I understand SwiftUI rebuilds the UI upon change of the underlying data and fetches the data automatically (after objectWillChange has been sent). Don’t know. Sorry, I am new to programming. Started during COVID. Lots to learn still, I know.

Comment: Like this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/manually-publishing-observableobject-changes (when objectWillChange is sent, SwiftUI checks for `value` and updates the text.

Comment: No problem. I don't know SwiftUI so I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstood something with `@ObservedObject`/`ObservableObject`. Will figure out what exactly went wrong. Listing to `onNext:` seems to be sufficient. No need to trigger before the change. Will accept your answer as it seems this is the best this question can get ;)